# When trying to access Google Docs from Android Firefox, I am stuck on "About" page

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, firefox, android

I was trying to log in to Google Docs from my phone. I am using Firefox on the phone. When I enter the address `docs.google.com` I am redirected to `google.com/docs/about`, which looks like this:

> [image]

The *Go to Docs* link leads to `docs.google.com/document/u/0/?gif=d` and when I click it, I simply end up back on the about page. I tried to log out of my Google account and log back in. That didn't help. I have no trouble using Docs or related features from my PC.

Why am I stuck in this loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Google Docs (and their sister products Sheets, Slides, *except Drive*) does not support mobile view, so when it detects that the site is accessed on mobile, it will:

- try to open their corresponding native Android app (if installed/enabled), or
- open the page normally, but then it will be automatically redirected back to the About page (tried with Chrome desktop on device mode, got HTTP 302 to https://www.google.com/docs/about)

I only figured it out that it is possible to access these pages on mobile browser by **requesting the desktop site**. *There is no mobile view*, thus even if the page is already loaded, turning off the desktop site will automatically redirect to the About page again.